# get USB drive name over VBA on WinCE

Tags: vba, windows-ce, drive

I need to get the name of the USB drive over VBA on Windows CE.

On Win 7 the Usb Drive is called "my thumb drive", on win CE I see it as "Hard Disk 2". Any way to read the real Thumb name and store it in a variable?

FSO (File system object) is not available on Win CE.

---------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

An alternative would be to retrive the modification date of a txt file, still in VBA on Win CE. (date File was created or saved, not accessed.)

Comment: USB Name or Drive Letter?

Comment: added an alternative solution to my original post

Comment: I have never worked with Win CE. Can you confirm if it supports APIs?

Comment: first time for me too so i am not sure. i can add references, but only existing/supported ones and FSO is not among them.

Comment: Ok let me post an API example and then you can test it for me? BTW you know the name and full path of the file right?

Comment: yes i know the name and the path. ok can test it!

Comment: VBA?  Windows CE doesn't support VBA at all.  There's also no kernel32.  What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve?  I think if we knew your end goal we could better steer you.

Comment: i am using a program called movicon. in this program i can write VBA scripts before i compile it and send it to the PLC running win CE6.0. within one of these scripts i must get the modification date of a file i know the path of.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Pass the file name in `Sub Sample()`

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenFile Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal lpFileName As String, lpReOpenBuff As OFSTRUCT, _
ByVal wStyle As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetFileTime Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hFile As Long, lpCreationTime As FILETIME, _
lpLastAccessTime As FILETIME, lpLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long

Private Declare Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib _
"kernel32" (lpFileTime As FILETIME, lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long

Private Const OF_READ = &H0
Private Const OFS_MAXPATHNAME = 128

Private Type OFSTRUCT
    cBytes As Byte
    fFixedDisk As Byte
    nErrCode As Integer
    Reserved1 As Integer
    Reserved2 As Integer
    szPathName(OFS_MAXPATHNAME) As Byte
End Type

Private Type FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type

Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print GetFileCreatedDateAndTime("c:\Sample.txt")
End Sub

Private Function GetFileCreatedDateAndTime(sFile As String) As String
    Dim hFile As Long, rval As Long
    Dim buff As OFSTRUCT
    Dim f1Time As FILETIME, f2Time As FILETIME, f3Time As FILETIME
    Dim stime As SYSTEMTIME

    GetFileCreatedDateAndTime = "Unable To retrieve details"

    hFile = OpenFile(sFile, buff, OF_READ)
    If hFile Then
        rval = GetFileTime(hFile, f1Time, f2Time, f3Time)
        rval = FileTimeToSystemTime(f1Time, stime)

        GetFileCreatedDateAndTime = _
        "Created on " & _
        stime.wDay & "-" & stime.wMonth & "-" & stime.wYear & _
        Chr(13) & _
        "Created at " & _
        stime.wHour & ":" & stime.wMinute & ":" & stime.wSecond
    End If
    rval = CloseHandle(hFile)
End Function
```

Comment: i get an error (in german). something like "awaiting a datatype for example integer" on your first kernel32 declaration

Comment: solved by reordering the the declarations. uploading code to plc.. will report soon

Comment: Works fine on Win 7 but on CE i get following error: `18.12.2013 16:14:28 System : Error executing Basic Script 'Button679' (line 14, offset 9) :         Expecting a var name.`

Comment: I wouldn't know what error means without seeing your code and also like I said I have never worked with Win CE

Comment: the only code i have is the one you gave me.. just reordered the functions and declarations. updating my main post with the current code that throws the error..

Comment: just saw that there is no kernel32 on winCE. there is just kernel.dll... tried replacing the name but does not work.

Comment: oops it could be a problem then :)

Comment: just found that on winCE there is coredll instead! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448387.aspx

Comment: This is where I will graciously step back as Win CE falls outside my area of expertise...